Django wizard form and htmx partials
I am building a django wizard form with multiple form, however in one of the forms i have a field of small list of sectors, and when the user select a sector i trigger a function that fetches the sub-sectors of that particular sector. the problem is when i tested the form in a separated html template it works fine, but when i use it in my wizard form it does not update the ui even though in the console i can see that the request was successful.
#urls.py
from django.urls import path # type: ignore
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _ # type: ignore
from core import views
app_name = 'core'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.OnboardingSessionWizardView.as_view(views.FORMS), name='start'),
    path('sub-sectors/', views.get_subsectors, name='get-sub-sectors'),
    path('get-started/', views.OnboardingSessionWizardView.as_view(views.FORMS), name='get-started'),
]

here is my view.py:
from core.forms import *
from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView # type: ignore
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse, HttpRequest # type: ignore
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _ # type: ignore
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404 # type: ignore
from django.core.serializers import serialize # type: ignore
from core.models import *
from core.forms import *

# Create your views here.

FORMS = [("contact", EntryInformationForm),
         ("information", PersonalInformationForm),
         ("business", BusinessActivityForm),
         ("address", BusinessAddressForm),
        ]

TEMPLATES = {
    "contact": "forms/core/_entry_information.html",
    "information": "forms/core/_personal_information.html",
    "business": "forms/core/_business_activity.html",
    "address": "forms/core/_address.html"
    }

def get_subsectors(request):
    subsectors = []
    sector_id =  request.GET.get('sector')
    try:
        sector = get_object_or_404(Sector, name = sector_id)
        subsectors = sector.subsectors.all()
    except:
        subsectors = []
    subsectors_data = serialize('json', subsectors)
    return render(request, 'partials/subsector_options.html', {'subsectors': subsectors})

class OnboardingSessionWizardView(SessionWizardView):
    # form_list = [
    #     (_('CONTACT'),UserEntryInformationForm),
    #     (_('INFORMATIONS PERSONNELLES'),UserPersonalInformationForm),
    #     (_('VOTRE ACTIVITÉ '),UserBusinessActivityInformationForm), # Business Information
    #     ]
    # template_name = 'onboarding.html'
    form_list = FORMS
    
    def get_template_names(self):
        print(f"Current step: {self.steps.current}")
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('Onboarding process done')

    
    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs)
        context['countries'] = Country.objects.all()
        return context

and this is my business activity template where i use that form:
{% extends "_base.html" %}
{% load i18n static %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block inner %}
    <div class="container mx-auto px-4 py-8">
                <ol class="flex items-center justify-between gap-2 text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 sm:gap-4 w-full mb-4 sm:mb-5">
                    {% for step in wizard.steps.all %}
                        {% if forloop.counter0 > wizard.steps.index %}
                            <li class="flex items-center justify-end gap-2">
                                <span class="size-6 rounded bg-gray-50 text-center text-[10px]/6 font-bold text-gray-600">
                                    {{ forloop.counter }}
                                </span>
                                <span> </span>
                            </li>
                        {% elif forloop.counter0 < wizard.steps.index %}
                            <li class="flex">
                                <span class="rounded bg-green-200 p-1.5 text-green-600">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-3 w-3" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M16.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414l-8 8a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 011.414-1.414L8 12.586l7.293-7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                                    </svg>
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        {% else %}
                            <li class="flex items-center justify-center flex-grow gap-2 text-blue-600">
                                <span class="size-6 rounded bg-blue-50 text-center text-[10px]/6 font-bold">{{ forloop.counter }}</span>
                                <span>{{ step }}</span>
                            </li>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ol>

    <form action="" class="space-y-4" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ wizard.management_form }}
                        <!-- FORM FIELDS -->
            <!-- Sector Field -->
            <div>
                <div class="relative mt-1.5">
                    <label for="{{ wizard.form.sector.name }}"> Domain d'activité </label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="{{ wizard.form.sector.html_name }}"
                        id="{{ wizard.form.sector.id_for_label }}"
                        placeholder="{{ wizard.form.sector.field.widget.attrs.placeholder }}"
                        list="sectorsList"
                        class="w-full rounded-lg border-gray-300 pe-10 text-gray-700 sm:text-sm [&::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator]:opacity-0"
                        required
                        autocomplete="on"
                        hx-get="{% url 'core:get-sub-sectors' %}"
                        hx-trigger="change"
                        hx-vals="value"
                        hx-target="#sub-sectors-list"
                        hx-swap="innerHTML"
                    />
                    <datalist id="sectorsList">
                        {% for value, label in wizard.form.sector.field.choices %}
                        <option value="{{ label }}" data-id="sector_{{value }}"> {{ label }} </option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </datalist>
                </div>
            </div> 

            <!-- Sub Sector Field -->
            <div id="sub-sectors-list">
                {% include "partials/subsector_options.html" %}
            </div>
            <!-- REST of the form ...... -->
        </form>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}

This my sub-sectors partial html template:
{% if subsectors %}
<div class="relative mt-1.5">
    <label for="subsectors">Secteur d'activité</label>
    <input
        type="text"
        name="subsectors"
        placeholder="Secteur d'activité"
        list="subsectors-list"
        class="w-full rounded-lg border-gray-300 pe-10 text-gray-700 sm:text-sm [&::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator]:opacity-0"
        autocomplete="off"
        value="{{subsectors.first}}"
    />

    <datalist id="subsectors-list">
        {% for subsector in subsectors %}
            <option value="{{ subsector.name }}" data-id="{{ subsector.id }}">{{ subsector.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </datalist>
</div>
{% endif %}

and finally, here is my forms.py:
class BusinessActivityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    activity_type = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(),
        choices=BusinessActivity.BUSINESS_CHOICES,
        label=_("Avez-vous déjà exercé une activité non-salariée ?"),
        initial=BusinessActivity.BUSINESS_CHOICES[0][0]
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = BusinessActivity
        fields = ['sector','when_to_start','commercial_name','activity_type']
        widgets = {
            'sector': forms.Select(attrs={
                'placeholder': _("Domaine d'activité "),
                'label': _("Domaine d'activité "),
                }
            ),
            'when_to_start': forms.DateInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('DD-MM-YYYY'), 'type': 'date'}),
            'commercial_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Nom comercial (optionnel)')}),
        }

I tried everything but i can't get it to work. is there a better approach since the list of sub-categries is quite large and my main aim to do it this way is to give the user the ability to type and have legit autocomplete suggestions

My debugging technique is to look at the ids: I would check your ids for your various elements in the rendered page to ensure they match up as you intend. SessionWizard prefixes the names and ids of elements with the form name. Meanwhile when using includes of partials check that objects you expect to have values actually have those values -- I tend to just print them into the HTML so it is obvious!
Also, I noticed that hx-target is set as
hx-target="#sub-sectors-list"

But I could not immediately see in the code the target id on any element. Maybe it is subsectors-list?
Meanwhile if you are using a layout form tool such as Crispy, it also can change the id structure too (crispy templates add ids onto elements such as select.)
So the best idea is to render the page and check that the ids you expect are on the page and they match up with hx- targets etc.
